# RegEx to extract words in brackets not working

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match, exec

I am using RegEx and exec to extract words but it is returning the full first match, not all the matches separately.

The string is `'one two [three four] five [six] seven [nine ten]'`. The result should be `'three four'`, `'six'`, `'nine ten'`, instead of `'[three four] five [six] seven [nine ten]'`.

```
var text = "one two [three four] five [six] seven [nine ten]" 
var brackets = /\[([^]+)\]/g; 
var match; 
while (match = brackets.exec(text)) {
   console.log(match);
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the capturing group `([^]+)`.

`[^]+` matches any character, including newline as there is nothing specified in the negated character class.

Use the below regex

```
/\[([^[\]]+)\]/g
```

`[^[\]]+`: will match one or more characters except square brackets `[` and `]`.

```js
var text = "one two [three four] five [six] seven [nine ten]"
var brackets = /\[([^[\]]+)\]/g;
var match;
while (match = brackets.exec(text)) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

---

You can also use `/\[(.*?)\]/g` where `.*?` will match anything except `]`.

```js
var text = "one two [three four] five [six] seven [nine ten]"
var brackets = /\[(.*?)\]/g;
var match;
while (match = brackets.exec(text)) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```